# Memory Leak when using Pointer to AudioUnitSampleType in Struct - calloc

Tags: iphone, pointers, memory-leaks, struct, audiounit

I am coding an audio app for the iphone where I need to use some C code to deal with the audio files. In short, I have a memory leak that is causing the app to crash after so many files have been loaded. The problem is related to a Struct that I create that holds the audio files when read in. The Struct is created as follows;

typedef struct {

```
    UInt32               frameCount;         // the total number of frames in the audio data
    UInt32               sampleNumber;       // the next audio sample to play
    BOOL                 isStereo;           // set to true if there is data audioDataRight member
    AudioUnitSampleType  *audioDataLeft;     // complete left channel of audio data read from file
    AudioUnitSampleType  *audioDataRight;    // complete right channel of audio data read file

} soundStruct, *soundStructPtr;
```

The Struct is then Initialized in the header like this;

```
   soundStruct                  phraseSynthStructArray[3];
```

I then attempt to join two files that have been read into  `phraseSynthStructArray[phrase1Index]` and `phraseSynthStructArray[phrase2Index]` and put the combined file into `phraseSynthStructArray[synthPhraseIndex]` like this;

```
- (BOOL) joinPhrases:(UInt32)phrase1Index phrase2Index:(UInt32)phrase2Index synthPhraseIndex:(UInt32)synthPhraseIndex{

    // get the combined frame count
    UInt64 totalFramesInFile = inArray[phrase1Index].frameCount + inArray[phrase2Index].frameCount;

    //now resize the synthPhrase slot buffer to be the same size as both files combined
    //  phraseOut is used to hold the combined data prior to it being passed into the soundStructArray slot

    free(phraseSynthStructArray[synthPhraseIndex].audioDataLeft);
    phraseSynthStructArray[synthPhraseIndex].audioDataLeft = NULL;
    phraseSynthStructArray[synthPhraseIndex].frameCount = 0;
    phraseSynthStructArray[synthPhraseIndex].frameCount = totalFramesInFile;
    phraseSynthStructArray[synthPhraseIndex].audioDataLeft = (AudioUnitSampleType *) calloc(totalFramesInFile, sizeof (AudioUnitSampleType));


        for (UInt32 frameNumber = 0; frameNumber < inArray[phrase1Index].frameCount; ++frameNumber) {
            phraseSynthStructArray[synthPhraseIndex].audioDataLeft[frameNumber] = phraseSynthStructArray[phrase1Index].audioDataLeft[frameNumber];
        }


        UInt32 sampleNumber=0;
        for (UInt32 frameNumber = phraseSynthStructArray[phrase1Index].frameCount; frameNumber < totalFramesInFile; ++frameNumber) {
            phraseSynthStructArray[synthPhraseIndex].audioDataLeft[frameNumber] = phraseSynthStructArray[phrase2Index].audioDataLeft[sampleNumber];
            sampleNumber++;
        }


    return YES;
}
```

This all works fine and the resulting file is joined and can be used. The isuue I am having is when I allocate the memory here, `phraseSynthStructArray[synthPhraseIndex].audioDataLeft = (AudioUnitSampleType *) calloc(totalFramesInFile, sizeof (AudioUnitSampleType));` then next time the method is called, this memory leaks each time and eventually crashes the app. The reason I need to allocate the memory here is because the memory has to be resized to accomodate the joined file which varies in length depending on the size of the input files.

I cannot free the memory after the operation as its needed elsewhere after the method has been called and I have tried to free it before (in joinPhrases method above), but this does not seem to work. I have also tried using realloc to free/reallocate the memory by passing the pointer to the previously allocated memory but this casues a crash stating EXEC_BAD_ACCESS.

I am not a seasoned C programmer and Cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here to cause the leak. I would appreciate some advice to help me track down this issue as I have been banging my head against this for days with no joy. I have read thats its a bad idea to have Pointers in Structs, could this be the root of my problem?

Thanks in advance,
K.

Comment: have you been using the Leaks tool?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
- (BOOL) joinPhrases:(UInt32)phrase1Index phrase2Index:(UInt32)phrase2Index synthPhraseIndex:(UInt32)synthPhraseIndex{

    // get the combined frame count
    UInt64 totalFramesInFile = inArray[phrase1Index].frameCount + inArray[phrase2Index].frameCount;

. . .

    void* old_ptr = phraseSynthStructArray[synthPhraseIndex].audioDataLeft;
    phraseSynthStructArray[synthPhraseIndex].audioDataLeft = (AudioUnitSampleType *) calloc(totalFramesInFile, sizeof (AudioUnitSampleType));
    if( old_ptr ) free(old_ptr);

. . .


    return YES;
}
```

And make sure that there is no garbage in phraseSynthStructArray[synthPhraseIndex]

Comment: Thanks for you comments max. I have tried this and it doesnt crash, a good sign! However, I am doing something similar in another method that passes the phraseSynthStructArray in like this: - (BOOL) readAudioFilesIntoMemory:(soundStructPtr)inArray and allocates memory like before: inArray[audioFile].audioDataLeft =(AudioUnitSampleType *) calloc (totalFramesInFile, sizeof (AudioUnitSampleType)); However, if I try to use your suggestion here, it crashes out stating "malloc: *** error for object 0xb716000: pointer being freed was not allocated". Any ideas why this is happenning?

Comment: Yes i ahve an idea. I wrote: 'make sure that there is no garbage in phraseSynthStructArray[synthPhraseIndex]'.  This means that when you're declaring a pointer (even if it's in a struct) it usually contains garbage, that points nowhere. That's why you have to initialize your pointers with NULL to be confident that they are not pointing somewhere. E.g. soundStruct s; s.audioDataLeft = NULL; s.audioDataRight = NULL;

Comment: I have tried that and I still have the memory issues. As you stated above I should set s.audioDataLeft = NULL. Does this not mean that in doing this I am ensuring that if( old_ptr ) free(old_ptr); never gets called, therefore no memory cleanup. Apologies for the simple questions but I feel that at this stage I am doing something fundamentally wrong. Have you any other suggestions that may help me track down this issue.